# can't able to get the particular row in the sqlite in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

In this above code the while statement is not executing and not displaying the value.can anyone pls tell me what is the mistake i done

```
NSString *sql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM district_details WHERE district_name = %@",test];
NSLog(@"THE VALUE FOR THE SQL1 IS .......%@",sql1);
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql1 UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        char *ID = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:ID];
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", field2Str];
        [myarray1 addObject:str];
        NSLog(@"the value of the myarray is......%@",myarray1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `while` statement even being reached? When you step through in debug, what's the value returned by `sqlite3_step(statement)` ?

Comment: Never use `stringWithFormat` to build your query. Properly bind values using the proper API. And be sure you finalize your prepared statement when done with it.